# Export to Oracle using QGIS

Tags: qgis, oracle-spatial

I have loaded a shapefile into QGIS and I now want to export it into our Oracle Database and add SDO_GEOMETRY. Is it possible to do this directly in QGIS? If not, what opensource options do I have to perform this task?

Comment: you might be better to have an oracle connection open and copy paste then commit rather than loading from shapefiles.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to this option. Are there any other alternatives?